# Sorting JPanels based on component

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jpanel

My program generates random numbers from 0 to 12 but if the result is 12 it would set dash as the text of JLabel, instead of the number generated.

Now, I wanted to sort my `JPanel` in ascending order based on the `JLabel` contents. In case of similarities in numbers, the black `JPanels` are placed on the left. It works fine except when there are dashes included, in which it doesn't sort properly. I would like to insert the `JPanels` containing dashes anywhere but it's not working as expected.

Screencaps from a shorter version of my program:

Pure numbers:

[image]

Dash included:

[image]

Here's the shorter version of my code (using the logic of integer sorting):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortFrames extends JFrame
{
    static ArrayList<JPanel> panels = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel sortPane = new JPanel();
    int toWrite = 0;
    int colorGen = 0;
    int comparison = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();

    public SortFrames()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<4;i++)
        {
            panels.add(new JPanel());
        }

        for(JPanel p: panels)
        {
            toWrite = rand.nextInt(13);
            colorGen = rand.nextInt(2);     
            p.add(new JLabel());
            JLabel lblToSet = (JLabel)p.getComponent(0);

            if(colorGen == 0)
            {
                p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                lblToSet.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            }

            if(colorGen == 1)
            {
                p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                lblToSet.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }

            if(toWrite != 12){lblToSet.setText("" +toWrite);}           
            if(toWrite == 12){lblToSet.setText("-");}           
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            panel.add(p);
        }


        sortMethod();

        for(JPanel p: panels)
        {
            panel.add(p);
            panel.revalidate();
        }

        add(panel);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void sortMethod()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<(panels.size());i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j<(panels.size());j++)
            {
                JLabel one = (JLabel)(panels.get(i)).getComponent(0);
                JLabel two = (JLabel)(panels.get(j)).getComponent(0);
                String lblOne = one.getText();
                String lblTwo = two.getText();

                if(!lblOne.equals("-") && !lblTwo.equals("-"))
                {
                    int comp1 = Integer.parseInt(lblOne);
                    int comp2 = Integer.parseInt(lblTwo);
                    JPanel pnl1 = panels.get(i);
                    JPanel pnl2 = panels.get(j);        

                    if(comp1 == comp2)
                    {
                        if(pnl1.getBackground() == Color.BLACK && pnl2.getBackground() == Color.WHITE)          
                        {
                            panels.set(i, pnl1);
                            panels.set(j, pnl2);
                        }       

                        if(pnl1.getBackground() == Color.WHITE && pnl2.getBackground() == Color.BLACK)          
                        {
                            panels.set(i, pnl2);
                            panels.set(j, pnl1);
                        }
                    }

                    if(comp1 != comp2)
                    {
                        if(comp1>comp2)
                        {
                            panels.set(i, pnl2);
                            panels.set(j, pnl1);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(lblOne.equals("-") && !lblTwo.equals("-"))
                {
                    JPanel pnl1 = panels.get(i);
                    panels.set(rand.nextInt(panels.size()), pnl1);
                }           

                if(!lblOne.equals("-") && lblTwo.equals("-"))
                {
                    JPanel pnl2 = panels.get(j);
                    panels.set(rand.nextInt(panels.size()), pnl2);
                }
            }       
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new SortFrames();
    }
}
```

I also have another method, which is by using `Comparator` class which also creates the same problem (this sorts equal numbers based on foreground but still the same as to sort equal numbers based on background so it has no effect on the said issue).

```
private static class JPanelSort implements Comparator<JPanel>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(JPanel arg0, JPanel arg1) 
    {
        JLabel one = ((JLabel) arg0.getComponent(0));
        JLabel two = ((JLabel) arg1.getComponent(0));
        String firstContent = one.getText();
        String secondContent = two.getText();       

        try
        {           
            comparisonRes = Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(firstContent), Integer.parseInt(secondContent));       
            if(comparisonRes == 0)
            {           
                if(one.getForeground() == Color.BLACK && two.getForeground() == Color.WHITE)
                {
                    comparisonRes = 1;      
                }
                if(two.getForeground() == Color.BLACK && one.getForeground() == Color.WHITE)
                {
                    comparisonRes = -1;             
                }
            }
        }

        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            comparisonRes = 0;
        }

       return comparisonRes;
     }       
}
```

Please tell me your ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier to sort data than to sort JPanels.

Here's mu GUI displaying your numbers.

[image: Sort Frames GUI]

So, lets create a Java object to hold the card data.

```
public class DataModel {
    private final int number;
    private final int colorNumber;

    private final Color backgroundColor;
    private final Color foregroundColor;

    public DataModel(int number, int colorNumber, Color backgroundColor,
            Color foregroundColor) {
        this.number = number;
        this.colorNumber = colorNumber;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.foregroundColor = foregroundColor;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public int getColorNumber() {
        return colorNumber;
    }

    public Color getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public Color getForegroundColor() {
        return foregroundColor;
    }

}
```

Pretty straightforward.  We have fields to hold the information and getters to retrieve the information.  We can make all the fields final since we're not changing anything once we set the values.

The sort class is pretty simple as well.

```
public class DataModelComparator implements Comparator<DataModel> {

    @Override
    public int compare(DataModel o1, DataModel o2) {
        if (o1.getNumber() < o2.getNumber()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o1.getNumber() > o2.getNumber()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (o1.getColorNumber() < o2.getColorNumber()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o1.getColorNumber() > o2.getColorNumber()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Since we keep the color number, sorting by color is as easy as sorting a number.

Now that we've moved the data to it's own List, we can concentrate on creating the GUI.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SortFrames implements Runnable {
    private List<DataModel> dataModels;

    private JPanel[] panels;

    private JLabel[] labels;

    private Random random = new Random();

    public SortFrames() {
        this.dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
        this.random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int number = random.nextInt(13);
            int colorNumber = random.nextInt(2);
            Color backgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
            Color foregroundColor = Color.WHITE;
            if (colorNumber == 1) {
                backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
                foregroundColor = Color.BLACK;
            }
            dataModels.add(new DataModel(number, colorNumber, backgroundColor,
                    foregroundColor));
        }

        Collections.sort(dataModels, new DataModelComparator());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sort Frames");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        panels = new JPanel[dataModels.size()];
        labels = new JLabel[dataModels.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < dataModels.size(); i++) {
            DataModel dataModel = dataModels.get(i);
            panels[i] = new JPanel();
            panels[i].setBackground(dataModel.getBackgroundColor());

            labels[i] = new JLabel(getDisplayText(dataModel));
            labels[i].setBackground(dataModel.getBackgroundColor());
            labels[i].setForeground(dataModel.getForegroundColor());

            panels[i].add(labels[i]);
            mainPanel.add(panels[i]);
        }

        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private String getDisplayText(DataModel dataModel) {
        if (dataModel.getNumber() == 12) {
            return "-";
        } else {
            return Integer.toString(dataModel.getNumber());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SortFrames());
    }

    public class DataModel {
        private final int number;
        private final int colorNumber;

        private final Color backgroundColor;
        private final Color foregroundColor;

        public DataModel(int number, int colorNumber, Color backgroundColor,
                Color foregroundColor) {
            this.number = number;
            this.colorNumber = colorNumber;
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            this.foregroundColor = foregroundColor;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public int getColorNumber() {
            return colorNumber;
        }

        public Color getBackgroundColor() {
            return backgroundColor;
        }

        public Color getForegroundColor() {
            return foregroundColor;
        }

    }

    public class DataModelComparator implements Comparator<DataModel> {

        @Override
        public int compare(DataModel o1, DataModel o2) {
            if (o1.getNumber() < o2.getNumber()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o1.getNumber() > o2.getNumber()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                if (o1.getColorNumber() < o2.getColorNumber()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1.getColorNumber() > o2.getColorNumber()) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The lessons to be learned here are:

1. Separate the data from the view.
2. Focus on one part of the problem at a time.  Divide and conquer.

Comment: Thank you! Very nice and detailed answer. I'll be checking this tomorrow and accept this as an answer. :)

Comment: Question: does this always place the panels with dash at the end?

Comment: @Friency Fernandez: Since a 12 is the largest random number generated and a 12 is replaced by a dash, then yes, the panels displaying a dash will always be on the right.

Comment: Okay I get it. Even though this does not place the dashes anywhere, this is a really good answer and it gave me the idea thanks!